# Issue with duplicating a google sheet to a new file - only range wanted - not all

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script that duplicates an entire google sheet to a new document and saves it in a folder when a button is pressed, however, I only want it to copy a specific range (A1:F52).

Every attempt I make at modifying the script to only have `.getRange("A1:F52")` throws an error that getrange is not a function, what am I doing wrong and how should it actually be?

This script functions perfectly as it is, but I just want it to only take the range across, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// SAVE INVOICE
function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {

  // SET VALUES IN CELL
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:F60').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('F3'));
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:F60').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  //COPY CONTENTS TO INVOICE SHEET
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('DO NOT EDIT');


  // SET SPREADSHEET MONTH
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('JANUARY 2023');
  let row = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  let activeRow = sourceSheet.getRange( 2,1,1,20);
  let last_row = targetSheet.getLastRow();
   
  activeRow.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange('A'+(last_row+1)+':H'+(last_row+1)),{contentsOnly:true});


  // REPLICATE INVOICE SHEET TO NEW DOCUMENT AND SAVE IN INVOICE FOLDER
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Get current active sheet.

  //GET SHEET NAME
  var sheet_name1 = sheet.getRange("F4").getValue(); // Get the value of cell F4, used to name the new spreadsheet.
  var sheet_name2 = " - "
  var sheet_name3 = sheet.getRange("A9").getValue(); // Get the value of cell A9, used to name the new spreadsheet.
  var sheet_name = sheet_name1 + sheet_name2 + sheet_name3
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1DVdganPrCfePk41kteKnXSqKmL4Pivu5"); 
  
  // Get the ID of the folder where you will place a copy of the spreadsheet.
  var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheet_name); // create new blank spreadsheet in a root folder
  var asFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId()); // get new spreadsheet as a file

  folder.addFile(asFile); // add this file to destination folder
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(asFile); // remove a file from root folder

  var copiedSheet = sheet.copyTo(newSS).getRange("A1:F52"); // copy active sheet to new spreadsheet
  copiedSheet.setName(sheet_name); // rename copied sheet
  newSS.deleteSheet(newSS.getSheetByName('Sheet1')); // remove "Sheet1" sheet which was created by default in new spreadsheet

  // run Clear function
  clear()
}
```

I am clearly mistyping the .getrange parameter as it throws an error, but I cannot work out what im doing wrong.

Comment: hello, there is no line with `getRange("A1:F52")`, could you include in the post the complete error you get from the Apps Script console and also points out which line the script is failing on ?

Comment: @ValLeNain, my mistake - I've added it now

Comment: could you add the error as well ? To be sure it's the `getRange` which fails. It could be `copyTo` if the new spreadsheet has not been correctly created